# GStream Backend Error could not demultiplex stream python error

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to compare subsequent frames to the first frame of a video using `compare_ssim` and then saving that as a separate video. But the output video gives me an error stating `GStream Backend Error could not demultiplex stream`. I made sure that the `frame_size` for the `Videowriter` is the same as what I am trying to record. The following is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity as compare_ssim

label = 0
initial_frame = None
start = True

video = cv2.VideoCapture("vid1.mp4")

frame_width = int(video.get(3))
frame_height = int(video.get(4))
frame_size = (frame_height,frame_width)
fps = 30
print(frame_width, frame_height, frame_size)

output = cv2.VideoWriter('output_video_from_file.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'), fps, frame_size)

while video.isOpened():
    ret, frame = video.read()

    if start:
        initial_frame = frame[:,:,2]
        start = False

    curr_frame = frame[:,:,2]
    (score, diff) = compare_ssim(initial_frame, curr_frame, full=True)
    diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")

    print(diff.shape) #same as frame_size
    label += 1
    print("On frame {}".format(label))

    output.write(diff)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Do you mean that `output_video_from_file.avi` is corrupted or are you getting the error where the above code is executed? Try adding `output.release()` at the end.

Comment: The code runs fine but when I try to play the avi video it is corrupted

Comment: Try adding `output.release()` at the end... Without it, the video file may be corrupted.